# Many database rows vs one comma separated values row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm creating a table for allowing website users to become friends. I'm trying to determine which is the best table design to store and return a user's friends. The goal is to have fast queries and not use up a lot of db space.

I have two options:

Have individual rows for each friendship.

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+
| ID | User_ID     | Friend_ID         |
+----+-------------+-------------------+
| 1  | 102         | 213               |
| 2  | 64          | 23                |
| 3  | 4           | 344               |
| 4  | 102         | 2                 |
| 5  | 102         | 90                |
| 6  | 64          | 88                |
+----+-------------+-------------------+
```

Or store all friends in one row as CSV

```
    +----+-------------+-------------------+
    | ID | User_ID     | Friend_ID         |
    +----+-------------+-------------------+
    | 1  | 102         | 213,44,34,67,8    |
    | 2  | 64          | 23,33,45,105      |
    +----+-------------+-------------------+
```

When retrieving friends I can create an array using `explode()` however deleting a user would be trickier.

**Edit:** For second method I would separate each id in array in php for functions such as counting and others.

Which method do you think is better?

Comment: Also consider that for a friendship relationship, if friendA is friends with friendB, that means that friendB is ALSO friends with friendA. Therefore, use the first method and only have one entry for each friendship relationship. You could even organize the table so that it puts the lower ID as a friend1_id column and the higher ID as friend2_id column. That way you know exactly how to search for an existing friendship between two people.

Comment: thanks for the advice! That's definitely something that I have to implement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First method is definitely better. It's what makes relational databases great :)

It will allow you to search for and group by much more specific criteria than the 2nd method.

Say you wanted to write a query so users could see who had them as a friend. The 2nd method would require you to use IN() and would be much slower than simply using JOINS.

Comment: my concern with 1st method is that for instance a user has 10,000 friends. You would have 10,000 rows. ..or a very large string

Comment: Exactly AlienWebguy, if one would be interested in how many friends someone has, he would just use Count and that's it, while in second case..

Comment: @CyberJunkie trust, thats what databases were made for. 10,000 rows for a properly indexed table is nothing.

Comment: Bojan, in second method you can easily `count($array)`

Comment: This is true, but who cares? Say a user quits the website - would you really want to search through every user's friend_ID 'csv' to see if that user id is present, and if so, repopulate that csv string??

Comment: @CyberJunkie yes, you can easily count the array after you've exploded the string into 10,000 array elements, something that is considerably slower and more intensive than just using the first method.  Also doesn't address the "finding people that have you as a friend".

Comment: @Alien: Secod method would not work with `IN` only. It would require `FIND_IN_SET()` which would be definitely slower.

Comment: @CyberJunkie: If I have a million friends, it would need a million rows (only). In the second method, how wide would the field need to be?

Comment: ypercude, good point, I wasn't aware that db tables can store so much

Comment: Thanks AlienWebguy, I'm convinced that multiple rows are better

Answer (score 7):

The first method is better in just about every way. Not only will you utilize your DBs indexes to find records faster, it will make modification far far easier.

Answer (score 6):

Breaking from [1st normal form](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) is usually not desirable because

1. Easy to Orpahned ids
2. Easy to insert invalid data types
3. Updates can require full table scans
4. Increases concurrency issues
5. No way to create the key (user_id, friend_id)

Answer (score 5):

Use the power of the relational database.  Definitely go with the first approach.  MySQL is faster than you think, and it regularly deals with VERY large datasets.